# Route in twig tamplate generating

Tags: php, view, routes, twig

I am generating download button and it's route via controller. As it's returning all data as it should, I am wondering why my data won't pass.

My route contains id of a user and dateFrom and DateTo parameters.

Error msg is:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given").

My code:

```
public function view($id)
{
    $user = $this->get('user')->geUserById($id);

    $dates = $this->get('app.service.bank_statement')->getInfo($user->getDateFrom(), $user->getDateTo(), $user->getUser());

    return $this->render('default/view.html.twig',
        array(
            'user' => $user,
            'dateFrom' => $user->getDateFrom(),
            'dateTo' => $user->getDateTo(),
        )
    );
}
```

And my twig view route:

```
  <a href="{{ path("view", { dateFrom: dateFrom, dateTo: dateTo, id: user.id }) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-centar"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-download"></i>Export</a>
```

Comment: your $user->getDateFrom() is probably dateTime object, you need to format it

Comment: can you show us user entity?

Comment: I added ->format('Y-m-d'); and it worked. Thanks a lot! :D @Zeljka

Comment: You can also format dateTime in twig like {{ dateTo|date('Y-m-d') }}